# Pasting a character and a integer using macro

Tags: c, macros

i was trying to paste  c and 4 and expected output as c4 but can't follow the same , what is problem with my code

```
#include<stdio.h>
#define paste(a,b) (#a)##b
int main()
{
    printf("\n%s",paste(c,4));
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You need a helper macro for the `#` "stringification". This is a FAQ, see the linked duplicate.

Answer (score 0):

```
#include<stdio.h>
#define stringize(a) #a
#define paste(a,b) stringize(a##b)
int main()
{
    printf("\n%s",paste(c,4));
    return 0;
}
```

`##` concatinates parameters but `#` stringize a parameter and you cannot use them together like this: `#define paste(a, b) #(a##b)`. That would give you an error

> error: '#' is not followed by a macro parameter